# Where are stored the temporary screen output session

Tags: linux, raspbian, temporary-files

I use Linux (Raspbian) and the screen command to execute python program.
I wonder where are stored the current information of a screen returned by the python program.

Indeed, when I attach a screen I can see some python outputs, but I am limited to the size of the window (physical screen).
If I use a larger (physical) screen, I can see more outputs.
Therefore I would like to know where are stored this information.

I precise I do not use the parameter to store any output of the screen.
Thank you

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I think it's just in the memory of the `screen` application, not stored in a file anywhere.

Comment: There are commands in `screen` that you can use to copy the buffer to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screen just stores the buffer in memory. Once screen exits, it's gone.

It also stores more lines than what is visible on one screen, but you have to use screen's commands to view them. The default is Ctrl-A, Esc after which you can use the arrow keys or Page Up/Down to navigate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't understand the buffer "thing" before... Here is a related link to increase the size of the buffer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351115/increase-buffer-size-while-running-screen?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa